# In PostgreSQL is there a way to impose a LIMIT to queries automatically?

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, triggers

**Initial Question**

In PostgreSQL is there a way to impose a `LIMIT` clause to queries automatically?

Suppose I have a table `restaurant`:

```
create table restaurant (
  id uuid primary key,
  name text,
  created_at timestamp)
```

First, I tried a view:

```
create view restaurant_limited 
as 
select * 
from restaurant 
order by created_at 
limit 3;
```

The problem with that is you can't apply a predicate and have it work, because the predicate gets applied *after* the `LIMIT`.

Next, I considered a rewrite rule.  However, as far as I can tell, the rule system allows you to substitute a new query, but it doesn't give you much power to *rewrite* an existing query.

Next, I considered a trigger, but triggers only seem to apply to DML, not to queries.

I suppose a function or a procedure could do it, but now we're getting out of the realm of a pure SQL interface.  *Surely* there must be some way to do this.  Any ideas?

**Addendum**

The reason I didn't want to apply the predicates first and then apply the `LIMIT` is because I wanted it to be general and support a wide variety of query patterns.  If users can submit more-or-less any query, then I don't know the predicates ahead of time.  Essentially, what I wanted was something whose *logical design*, if not *physical design*, would be something like this.

1. Accept an arbitrary `SELECT` query against a given table.
2. Treat that query as a sub-query of an outer query.
3. Automatically add a `LIMIT` clause in that outer query.

I could absolutely do this at the SQL console.  I could also do it in a middle layer, if the SQL is being generated within a middle layer (e.g., Python or Java).  What I was hoping was that there was some way within PostgreSQL to do this automagically.

Of course, the more I think about it, the more I realize this wouldn't be a property of any particular table, like a trigger or a rewrite rule is.  In fact, it wouldn't even make sense to apply it to individual relations.  It would *have* to be a re-write rule that would apply to *all* queries.  That sounds nice, and maybe it's available in some extension, but I wouldn't be surprised if there's no native way to do this in PostgreSQL.

Comment: I guess functions are the only way to achieve this.

Comment: I sure hope not.

Comment: Why not have predicates apply to restaurant table and limit apply to the resulting view?

Comment: I, too, suppose that this is only possible via functions.

Comment: Rajat, I can't have predicates apply to the restaurant table first in the view on that table, and then apply the limit to the resulting view, for two reasons.  First, if I want this to be general, I don't know the predicates beforehand.  Second, I want the limit applied automatically.  I tried to clarify this further in an Addendum to the question.

Comment: I know for a fact this can be done with an extension written in C using raw_parser to transform the parse tree, which is what the rule system does.  I'm just surprised no one has written that extension yet.  If that's true, I may have to write it myself.

Comment: As you wrote it's easy to do with a "generated sql", don't see any avantage/usage to have it directly in postgresql and I should not want to use such fonctionality. Let say you have a limit of 10, a table with 11 records, select * will return 10 rows. You have to rember your limit, and if you want the 11 rows, to change it, or to use a new command 'over limit'!

Comment: https://relay.dev/graphql/connections.htm#sec-Forward-pagination-arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to change the meaning of an SQL query in the way you want.

The canonical way to achieve that is by using a cursor:

```
BEGIN;  -- cursors need a transaction

DECLARE c CURSOR FOR SELECT ...;

FETCH 50 FROM c;

COMMIT;
```

This is a cursor in SQL, but your client API will have a way to declare cursors as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to go through a proxy, you can rewrite the requests (and responses) to your heart's content -- see https://dzone.com/articles/query-substitution

In your case, a few lines of code in the proxy should allow you to add the limit to the SQL where needed.